# How to get the indexpath of UISwitch in dynamic tableview using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I'm creating an online Test app. In that for selecting the subject, I have a dynamic tableview with UISwitch.  In that table I have 10 subjects in 10 rows. I need to find the **indexPath** of each switch to get the subject name.

I'm new to ios. I need the answer in swift.

Comment: can you show your layout or your tried code

Comment: see this link http://blog.seancarpenter.net/2013/01/10/putting-a-uiswitch-in-a-uitableviewcell/

Comment: sorry i need in swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code will be in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
  var subSwitch:UISwitch! //your switch or you can get this by viewWithTag also
            subSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
            subSwitch.addTarget(self, action: "swichValueChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

now get evnt for value change

```
 func swichValueChange (sender : UISwitch)
    {
       var id:String = sender.restorationIdentifier
    //here you can identify,which Switch is changed
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

         //here you can get uiswitch object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Simple code to find indexpath from Subview

```
func indexPathForCellContainingView(switch: UISwitch, inTableView tableView:UITableView) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let viewCenterRelativeToTableview = tableView.convertPoint(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds)), fromView:view)
    return tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(viewCenterRelativeToTableview)
}
```